# How to apply proper .env file to build-android step in Bitrise with 3 variants simultaneously?

Tags: android, react-native, bitrise

I want to use `build-android` script once with 3 variants (dev, stg, prod) and it is allowed:

[image: Build-android step variant section]

However, I only get .env file applied once, it is the .env.develop (because developRelease is specified first?

Can I somehow apply 3 different .env files for those 3 variant builds in one step?

Comment: Do you have logs or more detail about what's not working? From this my guess would be that you don't have the remaining 2 .env files committed into your repo (which, if those include secrets, is a good thing, you shouldn't). If that's the case then those files aren't available on the build virtual machine after cloning the repo, you have to create them. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Probably the easiest is if you upload the files to Generic File Storage and download from there using the File Downloader Step https://devcenter.bitrise.io/en/builds/managing-build-files/using-files-in-your-builds.html#downloading-a-file-using-the-file-downloader-step